# How can I get the 'key' of a keyword from an XSLT TBB?

Tags: xslt, tridion, tridion-2011

I am working on the XSLT TBB (using the XSLT Mediator on Tridion 2011 SP1) to retrieve the key Value from the Keyword.

My Keyword looks like this.

```
Value: Some Value   
Key: Its ID is 123
```

It's a normal Keyword.

I have created a schema with a field. The values will be selected from List and from Category.

The component Source looks like this:
This is the Component source directly taken from the component of Tridion UI.

```
<Content xmlns="Some Name space">
    <keywordlink xlink:href="tcm:202-9737-1024" xlink:title="Some Value"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">Some Value</keywordlink>
</Content>
```

When I observed the tcm:Component source from template builder, I observed that there are no attributes present for the field.

```
  <Content xmlns="Some Name space">
    <keywordlink>Some Value</keywordlink>
  </Content>
```

I want to retrieve the Key value of the keyword.

I wrote a XSLT TBB like this. I am using XSLT mediator to execute XSLT TBBs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:simple="Some Name space"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0"
  xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:transform-ext="urn:tridion:transform-ext" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="#default simple xh">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content/simple:Content" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="simple:Content">
        <xsl:value-of  select="simple:keywordlink/@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select=document(simple:keywordlink/@xlink:href)/>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting blank output. I want to get the key value of a keyword.

I am getting blank output because in tcm:Component XML, there are no attributes.

I am not sure how can I navigate to that keyword.

I should retrieve the value of Key i.e. "Its ID is 123".

Can any one help how to do this?

Comment: Seems you forgot to provide the source XML document... There is nothing like `tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Content` in the XML provided in your question.

Comment: Looking at your Content XML, which attribute do you mean when you say "Key"?  There's an href attribute (tcm:202-9737-1024) and a title attribute. Neither of those seems to match your expectation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems it's impossible to get an xlink:href to the referred keyword in a Keyword field using just the XSLT Mediator.

To overcome this I created a .NET compound that "inflates" the extra keyword info in the XML. You'll have to place this compound just before the XSLT compound.

Code:

```
namespace ContentManagement.TBB.Templates
{
   [TcmTemplateTitle("Inflate Keyword Info")]
    public class GetExtendedComponent : TemplateBase
    {
       public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
       {
           Initialize(engine, package);

           Component component = GetComponent();
           XmlElement componentXml = component.ToXml();

           XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(componentXml.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
           ns.AddNamespace("ns", component.Schema.NamespaceUri);

           ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);
           InflateKeywords(fields, (XmlElement)componentXml.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("//ns:{0}", component.Schema.RootElementName), ns));

           ItemFields metaFields = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.MetadataSchema);
           InflateKeywords(metaFields, (XmlElement)componentXml.SelectSingleNode("//ns:Metadata", ns));

           Item xmlItem = package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Component, componentXml.OuterXml);
           package.Remove(package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName));
           package.PushItem(Package.ComponentName, xmlItem);
       }

       private void InflateKeywords(ItemFields fields, XmlElement element)
       {
           XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(element.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
           ns.AddNamespace("ns", element.NamespaceURI);
           Logger.Debug("NS: " + element.NamespaceURI);
           foreach (ItemField field in fields)
           {
               if (field is KeywordField)
               {
                   KeywordField keywordField = (KeywordField)field;

                   XmlNodeList nodes = element.SelectNodes(String.Format("./ns:{0}", keywordField.Name), ns);
                   foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                   {
                       XmlElement kwelement = (XmlElement)node;

                       Logger.Debug(String.Format("Keyword titel: {0}", keywordField.Value.Title));
                       Logger.Debug(String.Format("Keyword Element Value: {0}", kwelement.InnerText));

                       kwelement.SetAttribute("href", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", keywordField.Values.First(v => v.Title.Equals(kwelement.InnerText)).Id);
                       kwelement.SetAttribute("type", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "simple");
                       kwelement.SetAttribute("title", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", kwelement.InnerText);
                   }
               }
               else if (field is EmbeddedSchemaField)
               {
                   EmbeddedSchemaField embedField = (EmbeddedSchemaField)field;

                   XmlNodeList nodes = element.SelectNodes(String.Format("./ns:{0}", embedField.Name), ns);
                   int i = 0; 
                   foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                   {
                       XmlElement embedElement = (XmlElement)node;
                       InflateKeywords(embedField.Values[i], embedElement);
                       i++;
                   }
               }

           }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Key of the Keyword is not stored in the link (which really only contains the minimal information needed to look up the Keyword). So you'll have to load the Keyword and read it from there.

Yoav showed how to read other items from within your XSLT here:

http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/implementing-the-xslt-mediator-part-1/

This snippet seems relevant:

```
<xsl:attribute name="alt">
    <xsl:value-of select="document(simple:image/@xlink:href)/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Metadata/image:Metadata/image:altText"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

So the `document()` call loads the linked item (in this case a multimedia component) and the rest of the `select` then finds the value they are looking for.

A keyword XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:Keyword xmlns:transform-ext="urn:tridion:transform-ext" 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" 
    IsEditable="false" ID="tcm:1-233-1024">
    <tcm:Context>
        <tcm:Publication xlink:title="000 Parent Publication" xlink:href="tcm:0-1-1" 
            xlink:type="simple"/>
        <tcm:OrganizationalItem xlink:title="Places" xlink:href="tcm:1-37-512" 
            xlink:type="simple"/>
    </tcm:Context>
    <tcm:Info>
        <tcm:LocationInfo>
            <tcm:WebDAVURL>/webdav/000%20Parent%20Publication/Places/New%20Keyword.tkw</tcm:WebDAVURL>
            <tcm:Path>\000 Parent Publication\Places</tcm:Path>
        </tcm:LocationInfo>
        <tcm:BluePrintInfo>
            <tcm:OwningPublication xlink:title="000 Parent Publication" xlink:href="tcm:0-1-1" xlink:type="simple"/>
            <tcm:IsShared>false</tcm:IsShared>
            <tcm:IsLocalized>false</tcm:IsLocalized>
        </tcm:BluePrintInfo>
        <tcm:VersionInfo>
            <tcm:CreationDate>2012-06-11T09:09:03</tcm:CreationDate>
            <tcm:RevisionDate>2012-06-11T09:09:03</tcm:RevisionDate>
            <tcm:Creator xlink:title="TCMHOSTNAME\Administrator" 
                xlink:href="tcm:0-11-65552" xlink:type="simple"/>
        </tcm:VersionInfo>
        <tcm:AllowedActions>
            <tcm:Actions Managed="0" Deny="96" Allow="268560384"/>
        </tcm:AllowedActions>
    </tcm:Info>
    <tcm:Data>
        <tcm:Title>New Keyword</tcm:Title>
        <tcm:Description>New Keyword</tcm:Description>
        <tcm:Key>Key</tcm:Key>
        <tcm:IsAbstract>false</tcm:IsAbstract>
        <tcm:ParentKeywords/>
        <tcm:RelatedKeywords/>
        <tcm:MetadataSchema xlink:title="" xlink:href="tcm:0-0-0" xlink:type="simple"/>
        <tcm:Metadata/>
        <tcm:IsRoot>true</tcm:IsRoot>
    </tcm:Data>
</tcm:Keyword>
```

Comment: the document(simple:keywordlink/@xlink:href) in the sample XSLT looks to be the starting point for getting the Key from the linked Keyword (it's certainly what I'd consider for a pure XSLT approach). I have a feeling the real question here is "what's the XML structure for a Keyword?" ;)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen. There is some difference in XML of component taken from Tridion UI directly and the tcm:Component source taken from template builder. In tcm:Component  source I dont see any attributes for the "keylink". Can you help me, how do I solve my problem.

Comment: In that case you can also load the Component through document('tcm:1-23') and get the xlink:href from there.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this topic, but I'm having the same problem. Getting the component through document() doesn't get the extra attributes. Anyone who was able to get the keyword uri through the component xml?

Answer (score 0):

Implement this way:-

To get the Value field:-

```
document(simple:keywordlink/@xlink:href)/tcm:Keyword/tcm:Data/tcm:Title/text()

<xsl:value-of select="document(simple:keywordlink/@xlink:href)/tcm:Keyword/tcm:Data/tcm:Title/text()" />
```

### Result:

```
Some Value
```

To get the Key field:-

```
document(simple:keywordlink/@xlink:href)/tcm:Keyword/tcm:Data/tcm:Key/text()

<xsl:value-of select="document(simple:keywordlink/@xlink:href)/tcm:Keyword/tcm:Data/tcm:Key/text()" />
```

### Result:

```
Its ID is 123
```