# How should I get Keyword Key from DWT

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

This is similar to this [XSLT question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980316/how-can-i-get-the-key-of-a-keyword-from-an-xslt-tbb), but ultimately for DWT.

We can get a [keyword's key via a C#](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_F2911E7E7A1C471DB4934662D5AB6F95) TBB.

```csh
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.Schema);
KeywordField keywordField = fields["state"] as KeywordField;

String stateValue = package.EvaluateExpression("Component.Metadata.state");

package.PushItem("statekey", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, keywordField.Value.Key));
```

In DWT, I sometimes want the `key` of a selected keyword in a component.

**Is adding and getting these from the package the correct approach?**

`@@Component.Metadata.State@@` gets me the value. Referencing the key directly from DWT would be great, but I haven't seen anything to suggest DWT exposes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another alternative to John's answer. How about taking a similar approach to Will's "Get Component Template Uris" and write a TBB that iterates over a category's keywords and writes them out into the package with the desired output value? You'd then be able to use these values directly from DWT with a "double-evaluation" like:

```
@@Keyword${Component.Metadata.state}Value@@
```

Comment: Clever, I like the approach, this let's us pick and choose when to get the key. I presume we could do the same for keyword metadata.

Comment: You could do the same for pretty much anything. It's just pre-fetching the data. In the case of CT URIs it allows you to avoid hard-coding them. In this case it allows you to have easy access to values not normally available. The downside is that it's slightly wasteful in terms of processor cycles and memory (fetching and storing all that unnecessary/unused data)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect for this you would need to go down the TBB route as you suggest, or even write your own DWT function to expose it.

You can find an example of creating DWT functions here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/get-and-set-variables-in-dwts

Comment: Great answer. I think the only potential issue you'd need to work around with a Custom Function is that DWT only exposes the keyword value and not its URI nor any information about the category that the keyword comes from, so your C# code would have to search for the keyword (and hope that it was unique) across all categories, or allow passing of a category name/URI and you'd need to hard-code that in your DWT.

Comment: I see--from DWT the keyword is only "text." I voted for Bart Koopman's idea to allow the [ability to get keyword by key](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=3916) and left a pending comment asking for the converse--to get key by keyword (in DWT).